# Jensen's inequality for countable probability space

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, information-theory

One form of Jensen's inequality for the finite case, tells us that

$$ \sum_{x \in X} p(x) \log q(x) \leq \log\sum_{x \in X} p(x) \cdot q(x) $$

For positive p(x), and $\sum_{x \in X} p(x) = 1$, $q(x)$ real, and $X$ finite. I am using the $\log$, but any concave function could be substituted.

or the probabilistic version:

$$ \mathbb{E}( \log X) \leq \log \mathbb{E}(X)$$
Where $\mathbb{E}$ is the expectation of $X$.

However, is this inequality true for countable $X$? The book I'm reading (elements of information theory, 2006), seems to prove it for the finite case, but uses the countable case without mentioning it.

Also on wikipedia the it seems the first inequality in my post is only for the finite case, whereas the probablistic verson makes no mention of cardinality of the probability space.

Comment: ${\rm E}[f(X)]\leq f({\rm E}[X])$ holds for _any_ convex function $f$ and _any_ random variable as long as $X$ is integrable, i.e. ${\rm E}[|X|]<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, I suspected as much! Do you or anyone else have any literature about this?

Comment: I think Measures, Integrals and Martingales by Schilling has a proof of this.

Comment: It's also Exercise 3.3.8 in Cohn's *Measure Theory*.

Comment: You can look at this MSE answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513951/jensens-inequality-with-probability-one

Answer (score 0):

Sketch, for the case where $X$ has support over $\mathbb{N}$:

Consider the variables $Y_n= \min(X,n)$ for $n=1,2 \cdots$

Then $Y_n$ has finite support, and so we have $\mathbb{E}( \log Y_n) \leq \log \mathbb{E}
(Y_n)$

But $Y_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ as $n\to \infty$. Then $\log \mathbb{E}( Y_n) \to \log \mathbb{E}(  X) $ and $\mathbb{E}( \log Y_n)\to \mathbb{E}( \log X) $. This implies $\mathbb{E}( \log X) \leq \log \mathbb{E}
(X)$