# Jensen inequality first order differentiaton

Tags: inequality

Can anyone explain why this is true.

If a function f is strictly convex, then
$$f(E(x)) = E(f(x))$$
which means 
$$x = E(x)$$

I do not seem to be able to prove it.

Comment: You will need to work harder to reach equality.

Comment: The existence of convex functions can't obviouslyforce random variables to become constant. I suspect what you mean is if $f$ is strictly convex and your first equality holds then a.s. it implies the second or something similar. Please recheck the wording.

Comment: As stated, your claim does not hold. Jensen's inequality states only that $f(E(X)) \le E(f(X))$. Note that $X$ is a r.v.. If $X$ is degenerate, you get the trivial identity $f(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: @Macavity Yes i stated that f is strictly convex?

Comment: @aceminer : Macavity gives a corrected version of your question, so you should try to answer that one (i.e., prove that if $f$ is strictly convex and $E[f(X)]=f(E[X])$, then $X=E[X]$ almost surely).  To prove that $X=E[X]$ almost surely, you will need to use properties of strictly convex functions.  Do you know any such properties?  To start, it may help if you assume the random variable $X$ can take at most two distinct values (and then show it takes one of those values with prob 1 and the other with prob 0).

Comment: @Michael No i am not familiar with convex functions at all. I happened to chance upon it while looking at some other stuff and the lecturer mentioned it

Comment: Possibly this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513951/jensens-inequality-with-probability-one Though you may need to read up more on convexity and probability before tackling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, your claim is false.

Jensen's inequality states that $f(E(X)) \le E(f(X))$ for any (integrable) r.v. $X$.

If $X$ is degenerate (that is, $P(X=x) =1$), then $E(X) = x$ and the trivial identity 
$$f(E(X)) = f(x) = E(f(x))$$
holds.