# Show that $\mathbb{E}(\left| Z \right|) \leq \mathbb{E}(Z^2)^{1/2}$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

So we know that $\mathbb{E}(\left| Z \right|) = \mathbb{E}((Z^2)^{1/2})$. But how can we proceed from this? The sum of squares is at least the square of a sum, so we cannot really bound the RHS upwards. It is evident that $\mathbb{E}(\left| Z \right|) \geq \mathbb{E}(Z)$, but I am not sure how this helps.

Comment: Do you know Jensen's inequality? Note that the assertion is equivalent to $(E(|Z|))^2 \leq E(|Z|^2)$.

Comment: Jensen or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @saz No, I am not familiar with Jensen nor Cauchy-Scharz inequalities. I will thus look them up. Thanks!

Comment: See here for a proof of Jensen's inequality, which is a more general (but more useful) statement than what you have asked in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513951/jensens-inequality-with-probability-one